# Keras layer input type

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have designed a layer in Keras. This is the first layer of the network. The input to this layer must be an RGB image ie of shape (height , width , 3). However when i run the code , i get the following error.

ValueError: Layer sequential_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: [<**main**.CountPix object at 0x7fa9a5e81518>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

How should I input my image or what should I modify in my layer?

class CountPix(Layer):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(CountPix, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', shape=((200,200,3)),initializer='uniform',trainable=True)
    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an input.

```
from keras.layers import Input
input_X = Input(shape=(height, width, 3), dtype='float32', name='input_image')
```

Also, if your self.kernel line you need to explicitly tell keras it is has an input shape similar to this example:

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(height, width, 3)))
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you should include the import statements in your answer so that OP can understand where `Input` comes from

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I got the following error when "input_X = Input(shape=(200,200,3), dtype='float32', name='input_image')"           " TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (None, 200, 200, 200, 3). Consider casting elements to a supported type."